# How to disable this grub menu while boot on ubuntu 22.4 LTS?

Tags: boot, grub2, menu, gnu

I have installed fresh Ubuntu 22.4 LTS and noticed a grub menu when booting. I don't need this and i want to disable this.
I have tried grub timeout 10 to 0 and many grub editing but this still happens.

I never noticed anything like this before.

[image]